# Tensorflow REstart queue runners: different train and test queue

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, tensorflow

I would like to use the "fully connected" model to do both training and testing. I have a train.tfrecords file and a test.tfrecords file. I believe that the proper way to do this is to create a separate graph for training and testing.

The fundamental problem is that using OutOfRange errors and coord.should_stop() breaks any sort of encapsulation I've tried.

```
#main.py: I would like main to look clean like this:#
session=tf.Session()
model.init(session, train.tfrecords, test.tfrecords)
model.fit() 
model.eval() 
session.close()
```

That works completely fine as long as you only call only once either fit OR eval (as you can imagine). [I'm roughly following this implementation](https://github.com/raindeer/seq2seq_experiments/blob/master/model.py)

```
#model.py
from graph.py import MyGraph

with tf.variable_scope(scope,reuse=False):
    train_graph=MyGraph(train_queue.batch)
with tf.variable_scope(scope,reuse=True):
    test_graph=MyGraph(test_queue.batch)

def fit(self):
    coord=tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads=tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord,self.session)
    try:
        while not coord.should_stop()
            self.session.run(self.train_graph....)
        etc
    except e:
        coord.request_should_stop()
    finally:
        coord.join()

def eval_on_test_set(self):#similar to fit
    coord=tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads=tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord,self.session)
    try:
        while not coord.should_stop()
            self.session.run(test_graph....)
    except e:
        coord.request_should_stop()
    finally:
        coord.join()
```

Clearly what's happening is that coord is (1) closing threads, which in turn also (2) close queues, that can not be reopened easily later. I just don't know the way around that. coord.clear_stop() may be part of the puzzle, but I couldn't make it work.

Secondly, I have both a training and testing queue, but they're not both being used at the same time. Ideally the solution doesn't involve dedicated test-/train-threads that wait half the time.

Comment: can you use two different coordinators?

Comment: So that's the code as I currently have it. Sorry I'll edit to make that more clear. I construct each coord within the train/eval function... This should result in a "queue_closed" error on second call.

Comment: BTW, it's normal to see "OutOfRange" error while using queue runners, it's a bit misleading in that it's an informational message rather than an actual error, it's been fixed in 0.9 I think

Comment: Could you add more details about your `train_queue` and `test_queue`. Have you tried adding their queue runners to different `collections`?

Comment: OP: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: What I ended up doing is just never calling coord.request_stop/join until my entire train/eval/train/eval../test cycle was done. My attention has been diverted this past 6 months, so I haven't checked out v0.11 or anything

Answer (score 0):

looks like the cooordinators has some linkage with the current thread context. within the same thread context though you are having different graphs, sessions and cooridanators, if one of the coordinator terminates this may cause other coordinators to exit forcibly. i tried to avoid this problem with seperate threads for training and evaluation. hope this helps